# Combine text from multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql-server

I have set of rows that shows transfer locations for employees as below. The end location for the previous row will be the start location for the next. There are over 50,000 employees.

```
Employee name  transfer_date  start_location   end_location
 AA            1/1/2017       Canada           US          
 AA            1/1/2018       US               Italy
 AA            1/1/2019       Italy            Australia

 BB            2/1/2016       Spain            US          
 BB            2/1/2019       US               Luxembourg
```

I need to convert this as:

```
  Employee name  start_location   next_location1   next_location2   next_location3 
  AA             Canada           US               Italy            Australia
  BB             Spain            US               Luxembourg       NULL
```

Comment: what would be the maximum number of transfers in the table(in this example its for AA and there are 3 transfers)

Comment: What has your research shown you about possible approaches?

Comment: @George Joseph, there is no limit to the number of transfers possible.

Comment: In the example provided you have stopped at 3 transfers and the answers provided provide a template on how you could extrapolate the same for more transfers. Eg: in the ans provided by Tim, you may add a condition with rn=4 for the 4th location transfer

Answer (score 1):

Pivoting with the help of `ROW_NUMBER` is one option here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Employee name] ORDER BY transfer_date) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    [Employee name], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN start_location END) AS start_location,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN end_location END) AS next_location1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN end_location END) AS next_location2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN end_location END) AS next_location3
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    [Employee name]
ORDER BY
    [Employee name];
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo